# Word2Vec Skipgrams - Should couples span sentences?

Tags: python, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

## Background

I am trying to train a Skip-gram word2vec model using negative sampling. from what I understand I need to generate couples (target, context) and a label where 0 = not in context and 1 = in context.

## What I am unsure about:

Should we make skipgram couples sentence by sentence? or should we flatten the sentences in to one large sentence and generate skipgrams from that? **In other words, should the generated couples span sentences?**

The only difference between the two code snippets below is one of them generates couples that span the two sentences like so:

```
data = ['this is some stuff.', 'I have a cookie.']
```

**results**:

```
...SNIP...
[some, have]
[stuff, this]
[stuff, is]
[stuff, some]
[stuff, i]
[stuff, have]
[stuff, a]
[i, is]
[i, some]
[i, stuff]
[i, have]
[i, a]
[i, cookie]
[have, some]
[have, stuff]
...SNIP...
```

We can see that there are couples that stretch across sentences

Or we can have couples that don't span sentences:

```
...SNIP...
[some, stuff]
[stuff, this]
[stuff, is]
[stuff, some]
[i, have]
[i, a]
[i, cookie]
[have, i]
[have, a]
[have, cookie]
...SNIP...
```

## What I have done so far.

**Get data**

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                          remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
```

**Initialize some variables**

```
vocabulary_size = 8
window_size = 3 
neg_samples = 0.0
```

**Flatten the sentences into one large sequence**

```
sents = newsgroups_train.data
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= vocabulary_size, lower=True, filters=filters)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sents)
word_index_inv = {v: k for k, v in tokenizer.word_index.items()}
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sents)
couples, labels = skipgrams(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sequences)), vocabulary_size=vocabulary_size, window_size=window_size, shuffle=False, negative_samples=neg_samples)
word_target, word_context = zip(*couples)
word_target = np.array(word_target, dtype="int32")
word_context = np.array(word_context, dtype="int32")
```

## OR:

**Split dataset into sentences and generate couples based off each sentence.**

```
sents = [nltk.sent_tokenize(s) for s in newsgroups_train.data]
sents = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sents))

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= vocabulary_size, lower=True, filters=filters)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sents)
word_index_inv = {v: k for k, v in tokenizer.word_index.items()}
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sents)    
couples = []
labels = []
for seq in sequences:
    c,l = skipgrams(seq, vocabulary_size=vocabulary_size, 
            window_size=window_size, shuffle=False, 
            negative_samples=neg_samples)
    couples.extend(c)
    labels.extend(l)
word_target, word_context = zip(*couples)
word_target = np.array(word_target, dtype="int32")
word_context = np.array(word_context, dtype="int32")
```

**Print out our words**

```
for couple in couples:
    print('[{}, {}]'.format(word_index_inv[couple[0]], word_index_inv[couple[1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it doesn't matter that much either way.

Even when libraries/APIs talk about "sentences" they really mean "texts" which might be multiple sentences.

The worst case, if you wind up with some contexts spanning texts that have no essential relation, is that it adds a little noise to training... which might require a little more training to reach optimality on the other non-noise contexts. But often run-together texts are actually related, from the same original source, so such contexts might still capture real useful patterns, and thus be a net positive compared to smaller text fragments.

You could try it both ways and score the results against each other to see if one or the other is better with your corpus and end task.

Comment: Thanks I have been experimenting with both, they seem to give relatively similar results